# How to make space in the UIStepper

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i am new to swift iOS .. i spend huge time to figure. out but i failed here is my code :

```
  var numberOfItemStepper : UIStepper = {

        var view = UIStepper()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view

    }()
```

it is showing  like

[image]

but i want like this image ..

[image]

note: i have no idea how can i do it  please help me

Comment: Hi... The UI that is being displayed is default for the UIStepper control. To display a stepper like displayed, you will have to create a custom control with two UIButtons as well as a label.

Comment: Third link I checked after a quick search: https://github.com/parakeety/PKYStepper

Comment: @ZeMoon thanks it is my answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You don't, if using a `UIStepper`. `UIStepper` doesn't support the look you want. You will need to create your own custom control. It shouldn't be that hard, and would be a good exercise in creating a custom `UIControl` subclass. You'd add a plus button and a minus button, have those buttons invoke actions in your control, and then have your control invoke a `valueChanged` action in their target.

If you don't want to work that hard you might be able to find an open source custom control that does what you want "out of the box."

Comment: Write some code… Wait, what??? You're showing your age! ;)

Comment: @AshleyMills: LOL. I know, right? Why do work when you can get somebody else on SO to do it for you?

Comment: @DuncanC thanks i done